# Wordpress wp_query exclude word and category

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to exclude word 'Vape' and exclude category using wp_query. Is it possible?

```
$args = array(

's' => '-Vape',
'cat' => '-62',
'posts_per_page'=>'16',
'paged'=>$paged,
'orderby' => 'date',
'order'   => 'DESC'
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I use the code above but its not working. I don't get the items that have in their title the word 'Vape' which is right but i get the items of the category 62...any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `category__not_in`:

```
$args = array(

    's' => '-Vape',
    'category__not_in' => array( 62 ),
    'posts_per_page'=>'16',
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order'   => 'DESC'
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Edit: `category__not_in` expects an Array to be passed.

Comment: 'category__not_in' => ... did the trick but it should be like this 'category__not_in' => array( 62 ), otherwise does not work! Please edit your answer to accept it. Thank you!